# Как в Lazarus узнать, запаролен ли ZIP/Rar архив?

Tags: zip, freepascal, lazarus, архивация, rar

Пытаюсь узнать запаролен ли конкретный архив или нет. Для этого пробовал использовать библиотеку paszlib, а именно TZipper. Но я не смог найти ни одного метода или свойства, который был возвращал признак наличия пароля у архива. Библиотека в целом очень скудна.

Потом я решил попробовать библиотеку FreePascalArchivePackage. Создал экземпляр TAbUnZipper. В нем есть три свойства: Password, PasswordRetries и OnNeedPassword. Первое устанавливает пароль для разархивирования, второе возвращает 3 байта, что они значат, не знаю, третье устанавливает событие.

Каким способом можно узнать в Lazarus (FPC) признак пароля на архиве?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачу решил с помощью 7zip. Немного пришлось схитрить, т.к. для Лазаруса нет Враппера. Зато он есть для Дельфи.

Сделал так:

1. Нашел Враппер для Делфи (здесь есть подходящий: https://github.com/zedalaye/d7zip).
2. Внутренним сервисом Лазаруса переконвертировал модуль Враппера для Лазаруса.
   2.1 Добавил нужные пакеты по запросу компилятора.
   2.2 В методе T7zOutArchive.AddFile необходимо отказаться от преобразования GetFileSize(Handle, nil); т.е. оставить, как есть.
3. Положил в рабочую папку с проектом сам 7z.dll.
   3.1 7z.dll должен иметь такую же битность, как и проект. Если проект 64-бита, 32-х битную DLL не загрузит, естественно.

После этого можно пользоваться библиотекой.

Наличие пароля я проверил на архиве посредством установки функции обратного вызова (CallBack function). Реализация выглядит так:

```
  function ArchiveSearcher.isArchEncrypted(FileName: string; ClassId: TGUID): boolean;
  begin
    // CLSID_CFormatZip for ZIP
    // CLSID_CFormatRar for Rar
    result:= false;
    with CreateInArchive(ClassId) do
    begin
      bArchEncrypted:=false;
      SetPasswordCallback(nil, @PasswordCallback); // Установка обратной фун-ции
      OpenFile(FileName); // Открытие файла архива
      ExtractTo('', 1); // Тест архива
      result := bArchEncrypted;
    end;
  end;
// Сама обратная функция
  function PasswordCallback(sender: Pointer; var password: WideString): HRESULT; stdcall;
  begin
      //cout('Пароль нужен!');
      bArchEncrypted := true;
      password := 'password';
      Result := S_OK;
  end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Подпишитесь на событие и попробуйте открыть архив. Если событие сработает, то архив запаролен.

Comment: А что использовать в среде lazarus для открытия Rar? С Zip понятно.